# Language Switcher Disappears on Custom Shopware 6 Plugin Page

Tags: laravel, twig, shopware, shopware6

I am currently facing a challenging issue with my custom Shopware 6 plugin and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have.

My plugin creates a new page in the storefront, but I've noticed that the language switcher in the header disappears when navigating to this page. The switcher works fine on all other pages, so this issue seems to be specific to the pages generated by my plugin.

Additionally, when I select English as the language and navigate to my plugin's page, the language automatically switches back to German. This unexpected reset only occurs on my plugin's pages.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- My main template extends @Storefront/storefront/base.html.twig.
- None of my Twig blocks (for parts of the page) appear to overwrite or interfere with the main layout.
- I've tested for caching issues, but clearing the cache doesn't resolve the problem.
- There's no custom JavaScript in my blocks that might affect the header.

I'm not sure what's causing the language switcher to disappear and would appreciate any guidance on where to look or how to fix this issue. I am providing the code of my main Twig blocks below for reference:

```
{% block base_content %}
    <main class="content-main">
        <h1>{{ configPluginName }}</h1>
        {%
            include '@RcCarPartScout/storefront/page/components/listing.html.twig'
            with {'partscoutfields' : partscoutfields}
        %}

        <hr>

        {%
            include '@RcCarPartScout/storefront/page/components/drawing.html.twig'
            with {'partscoutdrawings' : partscoutdrawings}
        %}

        {%
            include '@RcCarPartScout/storefront/page/components/explo.html.twig'
            with {'drawingsingle' : drawingsingle, 'drawingsinglecoords' : drawingsinglecoords}
        %}
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance for any help or advice you can offer!

Best regards,
Ollo

Comment: Perhaps you need to include a missing block in your `.twig`, and, possibly call `{{ parent() }}` inside of it?

Comment: Hey Jacob, thank you for you answer. I will try it soon :-)